# Trouble with updating my Recycler View with new items

Tags: android, kotlin

So my main problem at the moment is trying to add data to my recycler view. Essentially I created a button that adds the string `"hello"` to a list and then tries to call `mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(dataSet.size)`. It adds perfectly to the end of the list in the logs, but I just can't figure out how to update the UI for it.

The only items I can manage to load at the moment are the items fakeItems that are created when I start the app.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var dataSet = mutableListOf<String>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    insertFakeItems()
    setUpRecycler()

}

private fun insertFakeItems() {

    for (i in 0..5) {
        dataSet.add("Item #$i")
    }

}

private fun setUpRecycler() {

    val mAdapter = MyAdapter(dataSet)
    val mList = list
    mList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    mList.adapter = mAdapter

    mList.orientation =
        DragDropSwipeRecyclerView.ListOrientation.VERTICAL_LIST_WITH_VERTICAL_DRAGGING
    //mList.disableSwipeDirection(DragDropSwipeRecyclerView.ListOrientation.DirectionFlag.RIGHT)

    // button

    val onItemSwipeListener = object : OnItemSwipeListener<String> {
        override fun onItemSwiped(
            position: Int,
            direction: OnItemSwipeListener.SwipeDirection,
            item: String
        ): Boolean {
            Log.d("Main", "Position = $position, Direction = $direction, Item = $item")

            when (direction) {
                OnItemSwipeListener.SwipeDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT -> {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Item ${position+1} deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    //todo: add deleted code here
                }
                OnItemSwipeListener.SwipeDirection.LEFT_TO_RIGHT -> {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Item ${position+1} archived", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    //todo: add archived code here
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    }
    mList.swipeListener = onItemSwipeListener

    fab_add.setOnClickListener {
        Log.d("Main", "Button pressed")

        dataSet.add(dataSet.size,"hello")
        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(dataSet.size)
        println(dataSet)
    }
}
```

}

And this is the adapter:

```
class MyAdapter(dataSet: MutableList<String>)
: DragDropSwipeAdapter<String, MyAdapter.ViewHolder>(dataSet) {

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : DragDropSwipeAdapter.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val itemText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text)
    val dragIcon: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.drag_icon)
}

override fun getViewHolder(itemLayout: View) = MyAdapter.ViewHolder(itemLayout)

override fun onBindViewHolder(item: String, viewHolder: MyAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    viewHolder.itemText.text = item
}

override fun getViewToTouchToStartDraggingItem(item: String, viewHolder: MyAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int): View? {

    return viewHolder.dragIcon
}

override fun onDragFinished(item: String, viewHolder: ViewHolder) {
    super.onDragFinished(item, viewHolder)
    println("$dataSet")
}
```

}

Comment: It seems that the problem is `mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(dataSet.size)`. Try: `mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(dataSet.size - 1)` instead.

Comment: The UI still fails to update when I do that.

Comment: Check `notifyDatasetChanged` to see whether the recycler view gets updated or not.

Comment: Do you mean doing this? _mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()_ or how can I perform that check?

Comment: Yes, `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: I tried calling it immediately after inserting the new item to the list, but no luck with that either.

Comment: It shows that the problem comes from your adapter. Please include its source code in question.

Comment: Include source to your Adapter. The problem could probably be from there

Comment: Hey guys I just added the code from my adapter, thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in Java or Kotlin you pass by value not by reference. So until you change the value of the dataSet you are using in RecyclerView, you won't get any effect.

Do something like this (:

```kotlin
class MyAdapter(dataSet: MutableList<String>)
: DragDropSwipeAdapter<String, MyAdapter.ViewHolder>(dataSet) {

    private var dataSet: MutableList<String>

    init {
        this.dataSet = dataSet
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : DragDropSwipeAdapter.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val itemText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text)
        val dragIcon: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.drag_icon)
    }

    override fun getViewHolder(itemLayout: View) = MyAdapter.ViewHolder(itemLayout)

    override fun onBindViewHolder(item: String, viewHolder: MyAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        viewHolder.itemText.text = item
    }

    override fun getViewToTouchToStartDraggingItem(item: String, viewHolder: MyAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int): View? {

        return viewHolder.dragIcon
    }

    override fun onDragFinished(item: String, viewHolder: ViewHolder) {
        super.onDragFinished(item, viewHolder)
        println("$dataSet")
    }

    fun updateItem(item: String) {
        this.dataSet.add(item)
        notifyItemInserted(dataSet.size - 1)
    }

}

In activity:

fab_add.setOnClickListener {
        Log.d("Main", "Button pressed")

mAdapter.updateItem("hello")
        println(dataSet)
    }
```

Comment: No problem :) If you have some other questions you can ask here :)

Answer (score 0):

You must call notifyDatasetChanged after changing recycleView items list.

Comment: I have tried with _mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()_ on my button press, but still nothing